# Getting grey out when i try to apply stroke for a blue background

Tags: adobe-illustrator

When i try to add stroke (800px) for a elipse tool to a blue gradient background, I am getting grey out, Image which i have attached will explain things more clearly. I just need that stroke to be a background of blue box, and need to remove grey out[image]

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is. Could you please clarify (edit) your question?

Comment: I think he is asking why the radial strokes extend beyond the artboard. Perhaps this is really a `crop` or `clipping mask` question?

Answer (score 0):

I get this some times, what fixes it for me is to pick a colored swatch, and then pick the color I want. Im pretty sure its a bug.